# Asynchronous socket callbacks do not work in Mono/Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, asynchronous, mono

I'm exploring porting a .NET C# application from Windows to Linux using Mono. The problem I'm stuck with is that asynchronous TCP socket calls do not work. This means that I can send data with no problems but I'm only seem to be able to receive the very first response from the socket (via Socket.BeginReceive()). The next BeginReceive() puts the thread into a wait state.

In it possible in principle that our socket code contains a bug but as it's been working flawlessly in Windows for years.

Thank you

Comment: Could you share a small standalone program that duplicates your issue ?

Comment: Sure, I've now reproduced the problem in just such a program. Granted, it's still using our server which would be unavailable to you. However the protocol is very simple as you will see.

Comment: Sorry, still can't master this site:-( The link to the program is http://www.sendspace.com/file/ptmwyy

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with the mono-2-10 branch (soon to be released as Mono 2.10) and master.

The Mono 2.6.7 shipped with ubuntu fails and so does Mono 2.8. <strike>I've found the problem and I am testing a fix.</strike>. The next releases in the 2.6.x series will have the fix (also 2.8.x if there's any, since we are moving to 2.10 in a few days).

Btw, you should report problems in Mono following http://mono-project.com/Bugs instead of here.

Comment: I confirm that the bug has been fixed (at least in mono 2.10), thanks. I verified it yesterday for the standalone project, however took time to test the original (larger) project as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a synchronous socket, do things work as expected?  That's a quick way to help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Have just tested a synchronous socket. it does work OK, the only difference is that the last two received chunks (53 and 12 bytes) are received as one (65 bytes).

Comment: Have also tried a small standalone server, will post the code later. Does not work either (in Linux), only two first messages come through. Thus this hopefully could be reproduced on any machine.

Comment: I've prepared a standalone server and client code reproducing the problem. Here is the link to the files: http://www.sendspace.com/file/a64q05. When built in MS Visual Studio 2008 and run in Windows 7, it produces a sequence of 5 pairs of messages (client<->server). When running in Ubuntu 10.10 under Mono (same MS binaries or built anew by Mono), it only produces 2 messages from client and 1 message from server. Note also that I'm running Ubuntu as a guest in VirtualBox within Windows 7, if that matters.